# How to use a SAS Token with Azure EventHubs/ServiceBus AMQP

Tags: azure, amqp, azureservicebus, qpid

Pre-Conditions:

- I have a Java application which is able to submit and receive a successful response back when submitting Claims Based request as documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas
- This results in a sas token of the form : "SharedAccessSignature sr=amqps%3A%2F%2F....."
- I am very familiar with SAS token when used from the REST API, but this is in the context of AMQP

Goal

- My goal is to distrbute the SAS token for use by untrusted publisher which uses the AMQP library Proton

Acceptable Answer will have the following

- Example usage of the SAS token to send a message to AMQP endpoint. The language can be any language which uses the Proton C binding underneath. Python preferred, Java is next best.

Since this point is often confused in posts like this, I do not want to use the policy key. I want to use the generated sas token.

Comment: have you got any updates please ?

Comment: It isn't possible. This isn't a supported use case according to MS

Comment: @bearrito do you have a citation for them saying it isn't supported?